# Which ActiveJob queue does ActionMailer use in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, rails-activejob

In Rails 4.2, ActionMailer supports using the new background job abstraction layer called ActiveJob. ActiveJob puts jobs into background queues to be processed later outside of the flow of code that pushed the job into it.

The question is, since ActionMailer now supports automatic enqueuing of emails with the #deliver_later method, which queue do those emails get sent into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: according to [the Sidekiq wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#action-mailer), the "mailers" queue.